# tensorflow error on running the seq2seq model

Tags: python, neural-network, tensorflow

On running the RNN tutorial [example](http://tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq/index.md#run_it) , I get the following error after a reading data line statements:

```
reading data line 22500000

W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1052] 0x3ef81ae60 Compute status: Not found: ./checkpoints_directory/translate.ckpt-200.tempstate15092134273276121938
         [[Node: save/save = SaveSlices[T=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT
_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOA
T, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/save/tensor_names, save/save/shapes_and_slices, Variable, Variable_1, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrappe
r/embedding, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2se
q/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Candidate/Line
ar/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/Mu
ltiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/M
atrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_at
tention_decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attenti
on_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embe
dding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnV_0, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnW_0, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decod
er/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell
/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder
/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attentio
n_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCel
l/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/at
tention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attenti
on_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRU
Cell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/emb
edding, proj_b, proj_w)]]
global step 200 learning rate 0.5000 step-time 14.56 perplexity 2781.37
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/tran
slate/translate.py", line 264, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/platform
/default/_app.py", line 15, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/tran
slate/translate.py", line 261, in main
    train()
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/tran
slate/translate.py", line 180, in train
    model.saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=model.global_step)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/training
/saver.py", line 847, in save
    self._save_tensor_name, {self._filename_tensor_name: checkpoint_file})
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/client/s
ession.py", line 401, in run
    results = self._do_run(target_list, unique_fetch_targets, feed_dict_string)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/client/s
ession.py", line 477, in _do_run 
    e.code)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.NotFoundError: ./checkpoints_directory/translate.ckpt-200.tempstate15092134273276121938
         [[Node: save/save = SaveSlices[T=[DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](_recv_save/Const_0, save/save/tensor_names, save/save/shapes_and_slices, Variable, Variable_1, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/EmbeddingWrapper/embedding, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell0/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell1/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Candidate/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/RNN/MultiRNNCell/Cell2/GRUCell/Gates/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/Attention_0/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/Linear/Bias, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnOutputProjection/Linear/Matrix, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnV_0, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/AttnW_0, embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decod
```

/default/_app.py", line 15, in run
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv))
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py", line 261, in main
    train()
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py", line 130, in train
    model = create_model(sess, False)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.py", line 109, in create_model
    forward_only=forward_only)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/seq2seq_model.py", line 153, in **init**
    self.saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables())
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 693, in **init**
    restore_sequentially=restore_sequentially)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 411, in build
    save_tensor = self._AddSaveOps(filename_tensor, vars_to_save)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 114, in _AddSaveOps
    save = self.save_op(filename_tensor, vars_to_save)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 68, in save_op
    tensor_slices=[vs.slice_spec for vs in vars_to_save])
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/io_ops.py", line 149, in _save
    tensors, name=name)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 343, in _save_slices
    name=name)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/ops/op_def_library.py", line 646, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1767, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/home/temp_user/.cache/bazel/_bazel_temp_user/7cf40d683d56020fae2d5abbde7f9f05/tensorflow/bazel-out/local_linux-opt/bin/tensorflow/models/rnn/translate/translate.runfiles/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1008, in **init**
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

ERROR: Non-zero return code '1' from command: Process exited with status 1.

So what is the cause of this problem as the other language model example is working and the library has also been built. As per comments I created the checkpoint directory , still throwing the same error:
tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1052] 0x400d2bbe0 Compute status: Not found: ./checkpoints_directory/translate.ckpt-200.tempstate9246663217899500702

Comment: Looks like it cannot find a checkpoint:

Not found: ./checkpoints_directory/translate.ckpt-200.tempstate15092134273276121938

Comment: @RafałJózefowicz what does that mean and how to deal with it?

Comment: Can you check if the directory exists? If not try to create it and run the model again. If it does, try clearing out the directory...

Comment: @RafałJózefowicz the directory did not exist , i created and ran again but same error :tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:1052] 0x400d2bbe0 Compute status: Not found: ./checkpoints_directory/translate.ckpt-200.tempstate9246663217899500702

Comment: How are you invoking the tutorial program? I notice that the error message has a relative path (`./checkpoints_directory/...`), so perhaps the working directory is not what you expect....

Answer (score 2):

I think this is one of the problems that arises when the previous checkpoint was not saved properly. You can correct it in the following steps.

1.You can delete the all checkpoint files and restart the training.:

```
rm checkpoint
rm translate-ckpt-*
```

Now, restart your training again.

Alternatively, you can remove the most latest checkpoint and start it from the previous checkpoint.

1.Go to the directory and delete the most latest checkpoint, in this case it is:

```
rm translate-ckpt-200
```

2.Now edit the checkpoint file. You might see something like

```
model_checkpoint_path: "data/translate.ckpt-200"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-170"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-180"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-190"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-200"
```

3.Remove the last line and set the checkpoint to a previous stage.

```
model_checkpoint_path: "data/translate.ckpt-190"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-170"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-180"
all_model_checkpoint_paths: "data/translate.ckpt-190"
```

4.Restart your training.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue running Sequence-to-Sequence Models. 
And creating the [checkpoint directory] before running the code solves the problem !